# Invalid call to setPhotoURL: after commitChangesWithCallback

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a user profile view, in which the user chooses a profile image from camera roll and a username. When everything is chosen, the user clicks on a createProfileButton that calls the following function:

```
@objc func createProfileButtonPressed() {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let firebaseStorageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_picture").child(uid!)
    let database = Firestore.firestore()

    // settings for disabling warning concerning firestore
    let settings = database.settings
    settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
    database.settings = settings

    let profileChangeRequest = user?.createProfileChangeRequest()
    profileChangeRequest?.displayName = self.usernameTextfield.text

    if let profileImage = profilePicture, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.1) {
        firebaseStorageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error:", error!)
                return
            }
            firebaseStorageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error:", error!)
                    return
                }
                print("Picture URL:", url!)
                profileChangeRequest?.photoURL = url
            })
        }
    }

    profileChangeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error:", error!)
            return
        }
        print("Profile created")
        var databaseRef = database.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["uid": uid!, "email": user?.email!, "username": user?.displayName, "profileImageURL": user?.photoURL?.absoluteString], completion: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error storing user", error!)
                return
            }
            print("user successfully stored!")
        })
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    })
}
```

I want the users email, username, uid and photoURL stored in a firestore document. However, what I get is this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid call to setPhotoURL: after commitChangesWithCallback:.'

This happens after the popToRootViewController function gets called. Why does this error message show up although I want to set the photoURL before I commit the changes?

Comment: photo url is create properly??

Comment: @SagarBhut yes, the url gets printed and is correct.

Comment: Your commit completion handler gets called before the downloadURL completion handler; your view controller is removed from the navigation stack at which point the profileChangeRequest is no longer valid, but you still attempt to set .photoURL = url on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on ekscrypto's comment. Your call to `profileChangeRequest?.photoURL = url` is taking place within the download callback, thus it going to be run after your call to `commitChanges`.

You need to put your `commitChanges` block inside your callback -

```
if let profileImage = profilePicture, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.1) {
    firebaseStorageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error:", error!)
            return
        }
        firebaseStorageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error:", error!)
                return
            }
            print("Picture URL:", url!)
            profileChangeRequest?.photoURL = url

            profileChangeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Error:", error!)
                    return
                }
                print("Profile created")
                var databaseRef = database.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["uid": uid!, "email": user?.email!, "username": user?.displayName, "profileImageURL": user?.photoURL?.absoluteString], completion: { (error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Error storing user", error!)
                        return
                    }
                    print("user successfully stored!")
                })
                self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            })

        })
    }
}
```